# Value Error and String exception

Tags: python

I am having issues with a ValueError working the way I want.

I have a function that is returning a string but I do not want it too evaluate to a ValueError if it is not raised from the function

**Sample Code**

```
def test(a):
    if a == a:
        raise ValueError('There was a error # 2')


a = 'a'
if ValueError:
    print "There was a error # 1"


test(a)
```

**Output**

```
There was a error # 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Test_1.py", line 13, in <module>
    test(a)
  File "/home/user/Test_1.py", line 5, in test
    raise ValueError('There was a error # 2')
ValueError: There was a error # 2

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I read the docs correctly it said it can be raised by a string, how do i prevent this behavior?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError

Comment: 1) `if ValueError` is always true and the `print` will always be executed. 2) Your function always raises the error since `if a == a` is always true. 3) You're not doing anything to catch the error. – I'm very unclear on what you're trying to do here. Maybe you're looking for the `try..catch` syntax...?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure why it was working before but I made it more explicit and it works now. Also the first example was more vague and I was trying to catch error from a function that was in the library.

**Sample Code**

```
def test(a):
    try:
        if a == a:
            pass
        raise ValueError('There was a error # 2')
    except Exception, e:
        str(e)
        return e

a = 'a'

b = test(a)

if type(b) == ValueError:
    print b
```

**Output**

```
There was a error # 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @deceze Here is the answer

Comment: This code is still mostly nonsense. I have no idea what it's supposed to accomplish.